# Apache access logs indicate GET requests for files I do not want "gotten"

Tags: apache, security

```
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:00 -0400] "GET /download/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:03 -0400] "GET /phpmadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:04 -0400] "GET /321/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:04 -0400] "GET /123131/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:05 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdminn/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:06 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdminhf/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:08 -0400] "GET /WWW/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:09 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmln/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:09 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin_ai/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:10 -0400] "GET /__phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:10 -0400] "GET /program/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:11 -0400] "GET /shopdb/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:23 -0400] "GET /mysql/dbadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:27 -0400] "GET /mysql/mysqlmanager/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0)"  
118.24.49.139 - - [25/Sep/2020:12:29:28 -0400] "GET /wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1057 "-" "Mo
```

This seems questionable at best, but I am fairly certain they are looking for exploits. Hosting using xampp (Apache) on port 80. Can anyone let me know if I should be legitimately worried? It seems troubling but perhaps there is nothing for them to exploit in my very basic setup.

Comment: Just a footnote - The logs didnt format properly but if you can help with this question I assume you know how to read these regardless - I can provide many many more examples. They have accessed my site no less than ten separate times in two minutes.

Comment: It's not really an issue if the files don't exist. It's more of an annoyance, which you can alleviate with some sort of attack blocker like fail2ban or an external firewall service. Its the files that they do hit that you want to worry about.

Comment: @aynber just to be clear if those files don't exist in the Document Root there's nothing to worry about? Thanks :)

Comment: Eh, not necessarily. For instance, phpMyAdmin usually lives outside of DocumentRoot, but can still be accessed thanks to an Apache directive. But was long as they're throwing 404's, you should be okay.